# how to read a specific chunk of a huge file

Tags: python

I have a Huge file around 2 GB with data like this:

```
>TRINITY_DN19211_c0_g1_i1 len=332 path=[619:0-331] [-1, 619, -2]
GTCCAAGTATTACACACCGTATGATGAAGCTAACGGTGAATTTTCAAAATGTGTGAAGTT
TGAGAATGGGTTGCGCCCTGAGATCAAACAGGCGATTGGATACCAGAGGATTCGAAGGTT
TTCGGAGTTGGTAGACTGCTGCAGGATCTTTGAAGAGGATTCCAGAGCAAGGTCAACTCA
>TRINITY_DN63782_c0_g1_i1 len=433 path=[411:0-432] [-1, 411, -2]
ATAGACACGAACACAAACACATAAATAATTTGAGAAAATAGAAGTGATTGAACTTGTTGG
TGTGGTACAGGTGTCAAACAAACCTTCAACCAGAAGTTTTGTTGCTGCATAAATCATAGT
GACACTCTGATATGATATCAAAGAAAATCATGTAACCCAAATACATCCCTAAGTATCTAG
TTGAAGCTACAGTCCACTAATTGTAACAATATTAAGTAATTATGAAATGAACCATTTGCA
>TRINITY_DN35855_c0_g1_i1 len=782 path=[760:0-781] [-1, 760, -2]
CAGGTTTAACTTTAACACCTCCGACCCTGCCTCTAAATTCCTGCACAGAAATTTGGCTTC
ACAATTAGGACATGTTTGGATAAACAGTTTAATGAAGCACTTTTTTTCATAAATTCTGGT
ATCTGGCTATAAGACCTAATAATCTGGGGATCTGTTTCATCATCCACGAAGGGAGCCCAA
>TRINITY_DN67801_c0_g1_i1 len=420 path=[398:0-419] [-1, 398, -2]
GTACAGAAGGAGATGAACCAGAACTTTGCCTATCTCTACAATCATCTCCTTATCCCTCCT
TATGACCCAGAGAATCCGGCTGCTCCTATTCCTCCCGTTGTGTCACTACAAATTATGCCT
>TRINITY_DN52435_c0_g1_i1 len=209 path=[187:0-208] [-1, 187, -2]
TGGTCAAACTTGTATGAGTTCTAAACTCCTTGGGTTTTCTGCTAAGCGAAAGCCGCTTGT
ACTTTAGCTTCTGTTTAGTTAGATAGCACCACCTCATAAGCGCAGTTCTGTTTTGAGGTT
```

I want to write a code that return a chunk which starts, say from the   the 5 line and ends if  encounters with a character ">" in a line. Out put like this. I want to extract many chucks like this:

```
 >TRINITY_DN63782_c0_g1_i1 len=433 path=[411:0-432] [-1, 411, -2]
    ATAGACACGAACACAAACACATAAATAATTTGAGAAAATAGAAGTGATTGAACTTGTTGG
    TGTGGTACAGGTGTCAAACAAACCTTCAACCAGAAGTTTTGTTGCTGCATAAATCATAGT
    GACACTCTGATATGATATCAAAGAAAATCATGTAACCCAAATACATCCCTAAGTATCTAG
    TTGAAGCTACAGTCCACTAATTGTAACAATATTAAGTAATTATGAAATGAACCATTTGCA
```

What would be the best way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear when do you want your chunk to end, tho - when it encounters a '>' at a beginning of a line or anywhere in the line, so I'll assume the first scenario:

```
chunk = []
with open("your_large_file.ext", "r") as f:
    for _ in xrange(4):  # skip 4 lines, use range() on Python 3.x instead
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        if chunk and line.startswith(">"):  # break on > if we're already collecting a chunk
            break
        chunk.append(line)
print("".join(chunk))  # or whatever you want to do with it
```

.

```
>TRINITY_DN63782_c0_g1_i1 len=433 path=[411:0-432] [-1, 411, -2]
ATAGACACGAACACAAACACATAAATAATTTGAGAAAATAGAAGTGATTGAACTTGTTGG
TGTGGTACAGGTGTCAAACAAACCTTCAACCAGAAGTTTTGTTGCTGCATAAATCATAGT
GACACTCTGATATGATATCAAAGAAAATCATGTAACCCAAATACATCCCTAAGTATCTAG
TTGAAGCTACAGTCCACTAATTGTAACAATATTAAGTAATTATGAAATGAACCATTTGCA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function if you know from which line the data starts:

```
def extract_chunk(start_line):
    """
    start_line is the line number where your data starts, counting from 0
    """
    lines = []
    with open("data.txt") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i == start_line:
                lines.append(line)
            elif not line.startswith(">") and i > start_line:
                lines.append(line)
            elif line.startswith(">"):
                break
    return "".join(lines)
```

Comment: Using `"\n"` in `join()` call will result in double new lines as the file's `line` already has `"\n"` at the end.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Do you need to prepend your lines with spaces like you have shown in the example?

Comment: In my example I use an empty string to join back the whole chunk as it is within the file as I have a feeling that's what the OP was aiming at.

Answer (score 0):

This could be another solution for the same,

```
def get_chuck():
    full_str = ""

    # file1.txt in my case where I have mocked your data
    with open("file1.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            full_str += line

    full_str = [">"+x for x in full_str.split(">")[1:]]
    print full_str[0]
    # use full_str for your need

get_chuck()
```

Output

```
    >TRINITY_DN19211_c0_g1_i1 len=332 path=[619:0-331] [-1, 619, -2]
    GTCCAAGTATTACACACCGTATGATGAAGCTAACGGTGAATTTTCAAAATGTGTGAAGTT
    TGAGAATGGGTTGCGCCCTGAGATCAAACAGGCGATTGGATACCAGAGGATTCGAAGGTT
    TTCGGAGTTGGTAGACTGCTGCAGGATCTTTGAAGAGGATTCCAGAGCAAGGTCAACTCA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start_ln = 4
chunk = []
with open("data.txt", buffer=2**12) as f:  # buffering helps for speed of processing
   for i, ln in enumerate(f):
        if start_ln == i:
           chunk.append(ln)
        elif start_ln < i:
           chunk.append(ln)
        elif line.startswith(">"):
           break
```